# missing a using directive or an assembly reference after adding them both

Tags: c#, .net

Solution contains 2 projects:

Geo.Data project, which contains CodeRepository class, defined in namespace Geo.Data

ConsoleApp1 project, in which I have Program.cs class, where I want to instantiate CodeRepository from the other project.

So, I add to ConsoleApp1 - project references - the assembly from Geo.Data\Bin\Debug\Geo.Data.dll; I also add a using directive on top of Program.cs: using Geo.Data;

```
using Geo.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Geo.Data.CodeRepository x = new Geo.Data.CodeRepository();
        // here, if I add x. after the dot I can all methods listed (from class CodeRepository)
    }
     }
}
```

CodeRepository is coloured accordingly, so it's recognized as being part of Geo.Data

However, I do get an error when running the solution. Just don't see what I am doing wrong:

> The type or namespace name 'Geo' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)    ConsoleApp1\Program.cs

As described earlier, I have already added both the using Geo.Data and the assembly reference to Geo.Data. Is this a conflict of diff namespaces or what? Thanks.
Also, after writing the first letter "G" in the using directive, it's suggested to me through intellisense to use Geo; so at that point it does find it. Problem is when I run the project. The error points to the using directive. Thanks!

Comment: Is the geo.data .net dependency higher than the ConsoleApp1 project?

Comment: in the Geo.Data what is the access level of the class you are trying to instantiate in you ConsoleApp1?

Comment: Are you using VisualStudio as the IDE ? It is better to reference the Geo.Data project from the ConsoleApp1 via right click in VisualStudio and then reference it.

Comment: Yes - don't add a reference to the dll, add a reference to the project.

Comment: Mansoor: CodeRepository (from Geo.Data) is a public class. Yes, I am usin g Visual Studio. What do you mean by right click and ref it? What I did was right click on references from ConsoleApp1, then browse to the place where Geo.Data.dll is generated in the bin of the Geo.Data project. So that's how I referenced the dll. Is there a way to reference the class similarly in code...?

Comment: I just found Project dependencies in the Project menu, selected ConsoleApp and ticked Geo.Data (it had no project ticked previously). Reran but I still get the same error.

Comment: rlee, I had Geo.Data as 4.5.1 and the other one, ConsoleApp1, as 4.5. I think it was a .net dependency issue. I set both to use the same target framwork 4.5.1 and now it's working! Thank you very much to all of you.

Comment: Please post `CodeRepository` class from `Geo.Data.dll`, to provide the complete perspective. Also currently you are browsing to the dll and adding reference, is this a strongly typed assembly, then you need to install in GAC ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference Geo.Data as a library, you need to right-click the project in your solution explorer, select PROPERTIES, and change OUTPUT TYPE to CLASS LIBRARY (note that Geo.Data does NOT need to be a part of your solution if you do this - you would build Geo.Data elsewhere).

Otherwise, if you want Geo.Data to be part of your solution(edit, update, build at the same time), then add your reference by ADD REFERENCE and choosing SHARED PROJECTS from the right-side of the reference window.